# reduce image size when upload to server using in mvc 5

Tags: javascript, c#, html, sql-server-2008, model-view-controller

I have code for reduce the size of image but I not understand how can save that image into sql server database, if you have logic about that then please give me.
below is my server side code,

```
 HttpPostedFileBase pphoto;   
string filename = Path.GetFileName(pphoto.FileName);
  string targetPath = Server.MapPath("Images/" + filename);
 Stream strm = pphoto.InputStream;
 var targetFile = targetPath;
//Based on scalefactor image size will vary
 /*generate thumbnales*/
  using (var image = Image.FromStream(strm))
{
var newWidth = (int)(image.Width * 0.5);
var newHeight = (int)(image.Height *0.5);    
var thumbnailImg = new Bitmap(newWidth, newHeight);
 var thumbGraph = Graphics.FromImage(thumbnailImg);
 var thumbGraph = Graphics.FromImage(thumbnailImg);
thumbGraph.CompositingQuality =CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
thumbGraph.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
 thumbGraph.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
 var imageRectangle = new Rectangle(0, 0,newWidth, newHeight);
 thumbGraph.DrawImage(image, imageRectangle);
 thumbnailImg.Save(targetPath, image.RawFormat);
}
```

Comment: Have a look at [filestream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/blob/filestream-sql-server) in sql server. Or you could also check out [blob type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/blob/binary-large-object-blob-data-sql-server).

Comment: my database is ready. I use image datatype for that but want code for reduce image size and store into sql server database. if you know that then please send that code